# iOS: Can I store a managed object in a dictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c

For my UINotifications I want to store a unique key in the userInfo. So in my app you can only set one reminder per friend you have. So I want to store my friend object as a key. Is that possible? Or is there only a reference saved and no match can be made later on? Because the name of the friend could change so I don't know what else to save there to match clearly...

```
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:self.reminderFriend forKey:@"ReminderForFriend"];
            localNotification.userInfo = infoDict;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use instance of NSManagedObjectID of the friend as the key because it is unique and you can also get the NSManagedObject with that objectID from the store and do any type of comparisons you like later on. ObjectID is like primary key and so its unique.

```
-(NSManagedObject *)existingObjectWithID:(NSManagedObjectID *)objectID
                                   error:(NSError **)error
Fetches the object from the store that has that ID, or nil if it doesn't exist.
```

Comment: Sure I will (can only do that in 10 minutes :-) One last question: How can I compare two ids? == probably won't work?

Comment: ok :) by comparing two ids you mean that you want to actually compare two objects to check whether they are same or not in the store ?

Comment: Yes basically I want to store this object id in the Dictionary and later on check if from my current managed object the object id is the same as the stored object id.

Comment: For that u can compare objectID URIRepresentations with each other i.e [[objectID URIRepresentation] isEqual:[objectID2 URIRepresentation]]